# Озвучивание времени при срабатывани будильника IOS

Tags: ios, swift4

В Самсунг есть фича, при срабатывании будильника, они сначала озвучивает время, а потом играет Мелодию.
Есть ли способ реализовать это на iOS ?

Comment: Вы делаете свой будильник чтоли??? (Раз swift4 указали) Есть метод для запуска аудио. Вот ответ.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619607/how-to-play-a-sound-on-ios-11-with-swift-4-and-where-i-place-the-mp3-file

Comment: Я не нашёл ответа на вопрос, можно ли озвучивать время когда звонит будильник. Как использовать аудио я в курсе

Comment: Да, способ есть, и не один. Старайтесь не задавать вопросы предполагающие односложный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для произнесения текста в AVFoundation доступен класс AVSpeechSynthesizer. Подготовьте для него строку со временем в словесном виде и подайте на озвучку.